# Continue Program execution

Tags: java

i made a program which is asking a user to enter a number of 5 digits and then program is finding the sum of those digits.
i want to know how can i make the program to ask for a number again and again after calculating once.
i want user to try again n again until he himself wants to quit.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int num=1362;
    int i,t=0;
    int store;

    for(i=0; i<=5; i++)
    {

        store=num%10;
        num=num/10;
        t=t+store;

    }

    System.out.println("The sum of the digits of 1362 is " +t);
}
```

Comment: How does the user stop the execution? With a keyword?

Comment: Use loops. Try to write it on paper with some pseudocode, then try to write Java code for that. Post your attempts and we will try to correct your mistakes.

Comment: Try a do-while loop. Asign one keyworkd to quit and other one to continue, asking to the user if he wants to quit press x if not press c (for example)

Comment: hava a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843169/loop-user-input-until-conditions-met) . Does it help you?

Comment: What you have written here is pretty much a _function_ or a _method_ that gets single results. Think about how you would call this code from other code to get the multiple results you want.

Answer (score 1):

Until the user writes something that is not a number the execution will continue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num=1362;
    int i,t=0;
    int store;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(in.hasNextInt())
    {
       t = 0;
       store = 0;
       num = in.nextInt();
       for(i=0; i<=5; i++)
       {
          store=num%10;
          num=num/10;
          t=t+store;
       }
       System.out.println("The sum of the digits is " +t);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: While this program happens to be exiting, so it has no effect, it is generally not a good idea to close a `Scanner` tied to `System.in`. There are multiple questions here on SO about why input is no longer read, and they trace to closing a Scanner on stdin.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
User enters 5 numbers, after that, the sum is calculated and the user is asked if he wants to repeat it (without exception handling).

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String repeat = "";
do {
    try {
        int[] digits = new int[5];
        System.out.println("Enter 5 digits: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Digit %d:", i + 1);
            String input = br.readLine();
            digits[i] = Integer.parseInt(input);
        }

        int sum = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            sum += digits[i];
            sb.append(digits[i]);
        }

        System.out.printf("The sum of the digits of %s is %d.", sb.toString(), sum);
        System.out.println("Repeat? (y/n)");
        repeat = br.readLine();

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO: handle wrong user input
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle io exception
    }
} while (repeat.equals("y"));

try {
    br.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO: handle IOException
}
```