# Trying to get an input that is only an int and between 1-3

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am making a TicTacToe game clone and need to get input about where the player want to place their selection.

Here is the code:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop user input until conditions met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843169/loop-user-input-until-conditions-met)

Answer (score 0):

`hasNextInt()` will only return integers. Checking otherwise doesn't make sense.

By calling `nextInt()` within the if statement, and again in the body, you're reading two numbers.

Try

```
int row = 0;
while (scan.hasNext() && row < 1 || row > 3) {
    String next = scan.next();
    try { 
        row = Integer.parseInt(next);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
        System.out.println("invalid input " + next);
    }
}
```