# how can you repeat a statement if a condition is not reached in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that asks you to input some data as a string then if the string is more than 6 characters long it will ask you to do it again until you input an answer with less than 6 characters then moves on to the next question, how can i do this?

Comment: You can use a loop...

Comment: Does this (and plenty others) answer your question? [Loop user input until conditions met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843169/loop-user-input-until-conditions-met)

Comment: have you tried recursion ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a while loop that is always true, then break when condition is met.

```
while (true) {
  System.out.println("Enter answer: ");
  String answer = sc.nextline();

  if(!answer.length() > 6) {
     // do stuf
     break;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without a break, using a boolean variable.

```java
boolean flag = true;
String answer;
while(flag){
   System.out.println("Enter a string with less than 6 characters:");
   answer = input.nextLine();

   if(answer.length() > 6){
      System.out.println(answer + " has more than 6 characters. Please try again!");
   }else {
      flag = false;
   }
}
```